# CSP Policy: Firefox VS Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, content-security-policy

I'm trying to do a porting of an [Chrome Extension](https://github.com/RobQuistNL/chrome-github-jira) to use it on Firefox.

The extension just display some informations about the Jira ticket in Github website. In Chrome it looks like:
[image: Chrome result]

Everything works well after change few things, except loading images from Atlassian (Jira) website.

[image: Firefox result]

Due to some CSP block:

```
Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://myproject.atlassian.net/images/icons/statuses/generic.png ("img-src").
```

What I don't understand, is that [Content-Security-Policy: img-src](https://caniuse.com/mdn-http_headers_csp_content-security-policy_img-src) is supported by both Chrome & Firefox since almost 10 years. So why do they act different?

The `content-security-policy` header contains for `img-src`:

```
 img-src 
    'self'
    data:
    github.githubassets.com
    identicons.github.com
    github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com
    secured-user-images.githubusercontent.com/
    github-production-user-asset-6210df.s3.amazonaws.com
    *.githubusercontent.com;
```

Full policy:

```
    default-src 'none'; base-uri 'self'; block-all-mixed-content; child-src github.com/assets-cdn/worker/ gist.github.com/assets-cdn/worker/; connect-src 'self' uploads.github.com objects-origin.githubusercontent.com www.githubstatus.com collector.github.com raw.githubusercontent.com api.github.com github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com github-production-repository-file-5c1aeb.s3.amazonaws.com github-production-upload-manifest-file-7fdce7.s3.amazonaws.com github-production-user-asset-6210df.s3.amazonaws.com cdn.optimize…ithubusercontent.com notebooks.githubusercontent.com; img-src 'self' data: github.githubassets.com identicons.github.com github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com secured-user-images.githubusercontent.com/ github-production-user-asset-6210df.s3.amazonaws.com *.githubusercontent.com; manifest-src 'self'; media-src github.com user-images.githubusercontent.com/; script-src github.githubassets.com; style-src 'unsafe-inline' github.githubassets.com; worker-src github.com/assets-cdn/worker/ gist.github.com/assets-cdn/worker/
```

So I understand why Firefox refuse to load it. But why Chrome do it without any problem?

Comment: Please post the full policy.

Comment: It's a bug in Firefox: https://bugzil.la/1267027. The workarounds are 1) to strip CSP from the page or 2) to fetch the images in your background script as blob and convert them via URL.createObjectURL or use FileReader API readAsDataURL.